# Реализация отображения комментариев в android приложении

Tags: android, комментарии

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать комментарии в приложении.

Приложение - интернет магазин. Комментарии могут быть к новостям, продуктам и ещё паре категорий. Нужно отображать, редактировать, удалять, добавлять.

Первое, что приходит на ум - `listView` и `editText` под ним или над ним, но у комментариев могут быть child комментарии, с одной степенью вложенности.

У меня возникла идея создать лист вью, который состоит из вьюшек, в которых есть кнопки управления комментарием, сам коммент и лист вью. Если комментарий парент - лист вью внутри вьюшки показан, в нем дети. Если child, то прячем лист вью и оставляем кнопки управления комментарием и сам коммент.

Но у меня возник вопрос, насколько разумна моя идея? Может быть есть какие то готовые паттерны проектирования подобных кейсов или просто дадите совет, как такое лучше реализовать? Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу на 100% утверждать что это подойдет, но данный вариант более адекватен. А элементы управления (ответ на чужой комментарий, цитата, оценить) пусть появляються по долгому тапу. Текст ListViewItem это родительский комментарий. Дочерние TextView - это подкомментарии к родительскому комментарию. На а элемента управления, как я говорил, по долгому тапу появяться как Dialog или как card с низу (как в telegram, если нажать долго на диалог)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652814/android-listview-in-listview

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо. Структура интересная, а оформление додумаю :)

Comment: @iamthevoid не забываем помечать правильный ответ)